# Android - Room Persistence Library - Access data both synchronously & through observer based on need

Tags: android, android-room

**Problem:**

I am using Room Persistence Library and so far everything is working fine except that there is a data from select query which I need synchronously as I am calling it from a Periodic Job (Work Manager's Worker). I have defined the return type to be LiveData as I am also accessing it for display purposes in UI and so observers are great for that but now I also need the same data in Job.

**Code Snippet**

```
@Query("SELECT * from readings ORDER BY date, time ASC")
LiveData<List<Reading>> getAllReadings();
```

**Tried**

I have tried the getValue() method in LiveData but it returns null as the data is not loaded in LiveData while making the query.

```
readingDao().getAllReadings().getValue() // returns null
```

**Possible Solution**

There is only one solution that I can think of which is to duplicate the getAllReadings query with a different name and return type (without LiveData) but I don't think this is a clean approach as it increases duplication of code just to get a synchronous return type.

Please let me know if there is any other solution or perhaps some way to synchronously access data from LiveData variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow main thread query when you initialize Room DB, but it's clearly not desirable. This will give you the synchronous behavior but will block user interface. Is there a specific reason you want this to be synchronous?

The reason why `getValue()` is returning null is because Room is querying data asynchronously.  You can attach an observer or a callback function to get result when the query is finished.  You can display the result to the UI or chain another call for sequential operation etc from there.

I use RxJava to wrap my query request for asynchronous query but I you can also use AsyncTask.

Comment: I completely understand that the queries should be run asynchronously and not on the UI thread or else it will block the UI. Like I mentioned in my question the problem is that I want to access the same query through the job which is already running in background so for that I need synchronous execution. If the queries are executed through UI then obviously I want them to be asynchronous which LiveData is already doing under the hood. I don't think I can run asynchronous code inside the job.